# Send email after placing an order in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, order-email

I want to send an email to customer after placing an order in Magento 2.

Please send/tell me how to extend the functionality in Magento 2

### Edit:

I have created my new module `Roshan_Checkout` inside `app/code` and in etc folder I created a `event.xml` file and call a method from there which is defined in my observer.

But, I'm not able to reach there in my observer and don't know how to extend the checkout functionality.

Would be greatful to you if you tell the step by step procedure to do the same. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have tried so far. What is it you are stuck on, specifically? Have you tried looking at what Magento does?

Comment: use `sales_order_place_after` event.

Comment: check link,you will get your answer->
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208792/24878

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the observer, specify the folder `frontend` or `adminhtml` in etc folder and inside that use `events.xml` then call the observer. You can get the order details in observer using `$observer->getOrderIds();`.

Comment: Can you please provide the name of the event which the observer should listen?

Comment: @ErvinLlojku, "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" is event name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to observe **ONLY** the frontend for placing order then you can you the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` in `etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="vendor_module_send_email" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SendEmail"  />
</event>
```

**Note**: This is not going to work if you have custom checkout extension which uses different controller name or you are redirecting customers to payment gateways pages.
In that case you can observe `sales_order_place_after` in both frontend and adminhtml because this event is triggered from the Order model `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` in `place()` method.

For sending emails you can search in Google and find some tutorial for sending emails from controller and you just need to move the logic to helper and use it in the observer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the event "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"  and in the observer use|inject transport builder class to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event "sales_model_service_quote_submit_success" in the file Module/etc/frontend/events.xml with content :

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
    <observer name="sendNewEmail" instance="Compay\Module\Observer\QuoteSubmitSuccess" />
</event>
```

In function execute() you can get order detail :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // code send email here
}
```

Then write your code for send email with order detail

Hope it helps !