# sales_order_place_after not triggering in magento 2

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, magento2.1.5

I have created `etc/events.xml` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
       <observer name="process_gateway_redirect" instance="Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer\ProcessGatewayRedirectOrderPlaceAfter" />
   </event>
</config>
```

And observer for it:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessGatewayRedirectOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderFactory)
    {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo 'here I\'m';
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $lastorderId = $orderIds[0];

        $order = $this->orderFactory->load($lastorderId);
        var_dump($order);
        die();
    }
}
```

But the **event is not executing**, one page success is shown.
I even tried creating the `etc/frontend/events.xml` with same code. Anyway the event is **not triggered**.

I have found that many people are using this event and discussing about other kind of issues.

Many friends are suggesting me to use `checkout_submit_all_after` and `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`. I know about these events and have used previously. But my question is still the same.

**Is it impossible to catch the `sales_order_place_after`?**

Comment: why you want to use the event: sales_order_place_after?

Comment: Which payment you are using ?

Comment: @KeyurShah Cash on delivery, or any other.

Comment: Okay just for confirmation put logger in `vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver.php` because in core `sales_order_place_after` event used. If you can see log then there must be something in your module

Comment: For temp. you can use this answer for log file https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/magento-2-replacement-for-magelog-method/92441#92441

Comment: After checking revert this changes

Comment: @KeyurShah, Okay, but if i'm not reaching observer then what is the use of this?

Comment: Please first check :) @Anime

Answer (score 13):

**sales_order_place_after** is not proper,bcoz of it is not fire every time.

`sales_order_place_after` naturally fires whenever call  `place()` of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and it's call depend on payment method.

As suggestion, iam suggestion to you use

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

It will fire both for frontend /admin order

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Please check my updated question.

Comment: I'm using "checkout_submit_all_after" event, but it does not fire when I'm trying to place an order using Rest API. But Works when I'm using native Magento 2 checkout. Can you please help me?

Comment: What are all details enclosed with sales_order_place_after like name, qty, price, etc @Amit

Comment: You will get all details of  order . $observer->getEvent()->getOrder() Provide the full info about the product

Comment: @Yudi In Magento 2 there is separate etc/webapi_rest/events.xml for the webapi. For performance reasons not all events execute on the API by default.

Comment: @AmitBera, this will not fire when tried to place an order using Rest API. But Works when I'm using native Magento 2 checkout. what is the fix for this issue?

Comment: @jafarpinjar read the micwallace answer..

Answer (score 7):

In Magento2 use Observer `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` for triggering event after place order

You can do this by using the Observer in

> app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

and in

> app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\MyObserver.php

file add code -

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Captcha\Observer\CaptchaStringResolver;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');

     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;

     echo "Do your Neccessary Work Here";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Please check my updated question.

Comment: The above example throws this issue **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null**.
@akgola - Can you recheck your code?

Answer (score 1):

This code dispatch `sales_order_place_after` :

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
```

Seems like you can use `$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();`;

Try to replace:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getOrderId();
```

Comment: Hello Nero, that is not my question. I have not reached the observer. Please do check it and suggest more.

Comment: You just use this event for basically observer after checkout or you are using API, Payment method?

Comment: Yes I'm using API of other payment gateway.

Comment: Try to debug inside `Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver`. If this file doesn't run, It means the event `sales_order_place_after` not fire. We will know the problem become from magento or your custom module

Comment: @NeroPhung What are all details enclosed with sales_order_place_after like name, qty, price, etc

Answer (score 0):

if you want to die out code, this `events.xml` should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="my_event_name" instance="Foo\Bar\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and the observer php:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $orderInstance Order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getRealOrderId();

        \Zend_Debug::dump($orderId);
        die();
    }
}
```

Note that if you try to place the order via the web view, Magento will detect the die as an error in the order checkout flow, and redirect most likely back to the shopping cart page. You want to test this route via command line or a tool like Insomnia (https://insomnia.rest/). You'll want to set it up as a standard POST to the URL http://mystore.test/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/945bd25fc5b88834ea460d967305fdc2/payment-information (replacing the cart id here with your cart id). You'll also want to post the JSON:

```
{"cartId":"945bd25fc5b88834ea460d967305fdc2","billingAddress" {"countryId":"US","regionId":"47","regionCode":"OH","region":"Ohio","street":["123 My Rd"],"company":"Mark Shust","telephone":"2165551212","postcode":"44133","city":"Cleveland","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","extensionAttributes":{"checkoutFields":{}},"saveInAddressBook":null},"paymentMethod":{"method":"checkmo","po_number":null,"additional_data":null},"email":"john.smith@gmail.com"}
```

Now when you execute the request with Insomnia, you should see your output, along with a Fatal error at the bottom. This is fine, as Magento will rollback the order because of the `die`. You can still test and debug your code this way though.